# CommandInvokationFailure error when building APK?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm getting the following error when I build my APK:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
    C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages
```

I wish to integrate "Leaderboards" in my app using Google Play Services. What should I do to fix this?

What I've tried:

- Reinstalling the Google Play Services plugin.
- Updating SDK: [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzuwV.jpg). (tell me if I did it properly).
- Made sure I have latest versions of "Extras/Android Support Repository" and "Extras/Google Repository".
- Installed everything in SDK Manager. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/poEFcfJ.gifv).
- Updating Unity.
- Restarting.
- Few minor changes.

Comment: Some useful links: [1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/760989/failed-to-re-package-resources-2.html) [2](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1074000/unity-5-android-build-failed-to-re-package-resourc.html) [3](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1011)

Comment: @UmairM I saw these websites before and they didn't offer me a solution.

Comment: Are you using both google-play-services and admob?

Comment: @UmairM I'm not using AdMob.

Comment: Can't believe you just installed everything. You will run out of space very soon. I have a possible solution. Is this solved yet?

Comment: @Programmer No, my problem still hasn't been solved.

Comment: Ok. You have never accpeted any answer even if most in your questions are very helpful and likely solved your problem. This is how to accept answer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png Check back your question and see which ones solved your problem then tick them. Let me know after you do this.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks for the reminder. I've now accepted 2 answers. My other questions remain unsolved.

Comment: Nice.Update your question with the version of Unity you are using and the **Minimum API Level** it is set to. Also, mention what Android version your Android device is running. Before I put my answer. Please create a new project then try to **build** it in Android. Not** Build and Run**. Just **Build** it and tell me if you were successful in building it.

Comment: @Programmer Hi. I'm writing this from my second account because my main account got suspended (7 days) for voting irregularities. Here we go: I'm currently using **Unity 5.3.5f1**. I have tried downgrading to  5.3.4f1,  5.3.3f1 and 5.3.2f1 but this didn't solve the problem. I have tried to change the minimum API level to recent versions and that didn't solve the problem either. Currently, my API level is set to API level 9. I have created a new project and tried to build the APK and the same error pops up.

Comment: @Programmer  I usually just **Build** my APK without building and running, so my device's android version doesn't matter here. Finally, I have removed Google Play Services Plugin from my Unity project and I still have the same problem! Even if I create a fresh, brand new Unity project, the error still comes up! I definitely need help now, because I can't build at all...

Comment: @Programmer Also, I couldn't find another way to communicate with you.

Comment: Try my answer. Comment under it if there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This absolutely will fix your problem.

Download the google_play_services from this link below :

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8298000_r28.zip

Then unzip it.

after unzip copy the file to :

android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/

Find version.xml file at the zip file:

android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/values/

and copy it to  :

Assets/Plugins/Android/res/values/

At unity folder

This is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, you have to copy the version.xml file from

> android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/values/

into

> Assets/Plugins/Android/res/values/

of your Unity project's folder.

Comment: I can't find `android-sdk` . Where is it?

Comment: Also, I don't have a `res` folder.

Comment: In unity menu, Edit-> Preferences -> External Tools -> SDk-path

Comment: create a res folder under Plugins/Android/

Comment: Thanks. But, I don't have `libproject` folder under `google_play_services`.

Comment: In android SDK folder : get it from Edit-> Preferences -> External Tools -> SDk-path

Comment: Where is it exactly? I can't find it. Here's a screenshot of SDK path: http://imgur.com/WugeBz4 This is the problem.

Comment: if its not in the folder then you can open it from Android Studio/Eclipse. If you don't have any then install android studio first. (https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager)

Comment: My SDK is updated. Look: http://imgur.com/LtSFkpO But I still have the same problem.

Comment: @UmairM I'm also interested in an answer to this.

Comment: @Dinovr make sure you have installed "Google API" not just Tools items. If you cant find "Google API" in SDK Manager. Just Install everything.

Comment: @Gog65 Follow instructions in my answer. Let me know if this works

Comment: still cant find "res" folder?

Comment: @UmairM I still don't have `libproject` folder under `google_play_services`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115982/discussion-between-umair-m-and-dinovr).