# Unity - Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm having some issues with Google Play Services and Unity 5.0.4. 
The issue occurs when I want to build my build my project, I get the following error

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.

I've read a lot and tried to fix it, but no solution been working for me.

I've got the latest Google Play serivces (Rev 32), Google Repository (Rev 32) and Android Support Repository (Rev 35).

I've also read that you can't have API 24 installed, so I've uninstalled and removed it completely. I can't find any other solution to my problem.

Whole console log:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>   C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe package
>   --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F
>   bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages
>   com.google.example.games.mainlibproj   stderr[ AndroidManifest.xml:19:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').   ]
>   stdout[ Configurations:  (default)  v14  v21  xhdpi-v4   Files:
>   drawable\app_banner.png
>       Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png   drawable\app_icon.png
>       Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png   values\strings.xml
>       Src: () res\values\strings.xml   values\styles.xml
>       Src: () res\values\styles.xml
>       Src: (v14) res\values-v14\styles.xml
>       Src: (v21) res\values-v21\styles.xml   AndroidManifest.xml
>       Src: () AndroidManifest.xml   Resource Dirs:   Type drawable
>       drawable\app_banner.png
>         Src: (xhdpi-v4) res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
>       drawable\app_icon.png
>         Src: () res\drawable\app_icon.png   Type values
>       values\strings.xml
>         Src: () res\values\strings.xml
>       values\styles.xml
>         Src: () res\values\styles.xml
>         Src: (v14) res\values-v14\styles.xml
>         Src: (v21) res\values-v21\styles.xml Including resources from package: C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar
>   applyFileOverlay for drawable applyFileOverlay for layout
>   applyFileOverlay for anim applyFileOverlay for animator
>   applyFileOverlay for interpolator applyFileOverlay for transition
>   applyFileOverlay for xml applyFileOverlay for raw applyFileOverlay for
>   color applyFileOverlay for menu applyFileOverlay for mipmap Processing
>   image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png Processing image:
>   res\drawable\app_icon.png
>       (processed image res\drawable\app_icon.png: 94% size of source)
>       (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png: 93% size of source)
>       (new resource id app_banner from xhdpi-v4\drawable\app_banner.png #generated)
>       (new resource id app_icon from drawable\app_icon.png #generated) ] UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
>   psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec
>   (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be following possible problems:

1. There might be some duplicate jar files in your plugins folder. Find them and remove one of them to fix this problem.
2. There might be an issue with merging data from more than one manifest files.

Check following posts to get the pointer :

1. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/commandinvokationfailure-android-asset-packaging-tool-failed-no-stderr-to-lookup.274631/
2. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1074000/unity-5-android-build-failed-to-re-package-resourc.html
3. https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/900
4. https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1011
5. [Error building player for Android in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957963/error-building-player-for-android-in-unity/36959457#36959457)

**EDIT :**

You are missing `res` folder in plugins.

1. Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38076937/4366237
2. And this forum post : http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/help-cant-build-project-after-trying-to-use-google-play-services.243284/

Comment: Those were the answers I found when I were looking for my problem. How ever, none of these did solve my problem.

Comment: Of course, I did post it as a pastebin: pastebin.com(/)bTTqiz84

Comment: See my answer in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39018661/6521156) this will fix your answer.

Comment: **this will fix your answer**... do i need to fix my answer?

Comment: oo sorry.. i mean fix the question problem :) miss typing