# "CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format." with Unity Upsight Plugin Build for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, dex

I am running into an Exception when I try to build my Unity project for Android since I imported and configured the Upsight (http://www.upsight.com/) plugin. The log message is truncated so I cannot see where the conflict comes from (see below).

It would be great, if someone knew how to find the exact source of this error. Maybe the truncating can be deactivated somehow or this problem is known for Upsight when using other plugins. I use some more plugins like Unity Purchasing, Mobile Social and Fyber. Maybe one of these is known to cause problems in combination with Upsight!?

I appreciate any idea or workaround. I need to get the plugin running.

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See
>   the Console for details.
>   C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M
>   -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/ggurbat/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools"
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -
>
> stderr[
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.a) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.banners.b) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.banners.BannerSize$1) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.banners.a) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.banners.c) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.banners.d) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.interstitials.a.b) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.interstitials.a.c) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.ofw.a) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.d) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.f) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.g) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.h) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.i) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.j) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.m) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.n) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.o) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.a.e) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.c) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.e) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.f) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.g) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.h) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.i) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.k) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.l) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos.b) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>   warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.fyber.ads.videos

Comment: This is not mainstream [Command Invokation Failure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38980377/4366237), I would suggest you to delete the plugin completely and reimport it.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem two weeks ago. This error usually comes when you have imported more than one plugins that have same ".jar" files in assets folder.

I suggest you to find repeating ".jar" in project folder by typing "*.jar" in search bar. And then find for repeating files and delete one of them.

In my case, I had imported two different versions of Google VR sdks. So they had same .jar files....
When I searched for them, i found "example.jar" two times in search results. and deleted one of them. It solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, this helps if the files are named similarly.

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes accross a similar issue: In "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor" (on Windows) you find the Editor.log file. This one contains the full log message including the class names that are causing conflicts. Then you can search all *.jar and *.aar files in your assets folder for those class names using a tool like "Windows Grep".
This allows you to locate the files and you will probably be able to delete those. Be sure to make a backup. Repete these steps until the error message does not appear any more.
If deleting causes other problems, you can edit them (open .jar files with 7zip or similar) and remove the specific classes.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by deleting the following files as they were the only 8.4.0 versions where as the others are 10.0.1.

Assets/Plugins/Android/play.services-ads-8.4.0.aar

Assets/Plugins/Android/play-services-gcm-8.4.0.aar

Assets/Plugins/Android/support-v4-24.0.0.aar

Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Android/lib/support-v4-23.2.1.aar

**Note:**
I resolved the android version and updated all play services to the latest using the following behorehand.

Assets -> Player Services Handler -> VersionHandler -> Update