# Failed to recompile unity project when google play services added

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

On google developer console my app has the package name `com.ultpult.catch.o` (new name) for getting xml to integrate google play services in my game

I had been successfully using google play services like (in app purchases) with package name `com.ultpult.catcho` (old name), but that time I had used `android native plugin` but now I am trying this with **default plugins of google for unity**.

Now when I import google play game services into unity and compile my unity project, i get error.

I have update my SDK manager to latest version

I also checked my environmental variables path, they are fine too.

But still getting following error when compiling/building the project on step `packaging and recompiling files`

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to recompile android resource files.
>   C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javac.exe -bootclasspath "C:/Users/imran.farooq/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\imran.farooq\Documents\Co\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "android\support\v4\R.java" "android\support\v7\appcompat\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\ads\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\ads\impl\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\base\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\clearcut\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\drive\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\games\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\nearby\R.java" "com\google\android\gms\tasks\R.java" "com\google\example\games\mainlibproj\R.java" "com\ultpult\catch\o\R.java"

```
stderr
[
com\ultpult\catch\o\R.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
package com.ultpult.catch.o;
            ^
com\ultpult\catch\o\R.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.ultpult.catch.o;
                ^   
com\ultpult\catch\o\R.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.ultpult.catch.o;
                 ^
3 errors
]
stdout[]
```

> UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity - Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979995/unity-error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-failed-to-re-package-re)

Comment: OK..will look and get back to you..

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue and i am happy after spending some time i have solved this issue

you have use `catch` in package name its java reserve keyword so it make issue in R file . try to use non java reserve keyword and it will be solve :)

I know its too late but for anyone who will get this kind of issue can get get help with answer