# CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. Unity, Ignoring InnerClasses

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, facebook-audience-network

Hope you all are fine.
I am trying to integrate Facebook Audience Network in my Android app which is developed in Unity, when I try to build the apk it throws following error

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/JawadAmjad/Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools"
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity 5.6.2p4/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar" -
>
> stderr[ warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous
>   inner class (com.a.a.ab) that doesn't come with an associated
>   EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class. warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class (com.a.a.b) that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod
>   attribute. This class was probably produced by a compiler that did not
>   target the modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to
>   recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and
>   without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of
>   ignoring this warning is that reflective operations on this class will
>   incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

In my experience in may not be multiple jar issue. I am not able to figure out a solution, please help me.

> Installed Android SDK Tools Version 26.1.1 Installed Android SDK
>   Platform Tool 27.0.0 Unity Version 5.6.2 p4

Your quick support will be appreciated.
Hope to get a solution soon.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity - Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979995/unity-error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-failed-to-re-package-re)

Comment: No, its not a duplicate.

Comment: try the solutions in my answer