# CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format in Unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics, google-play-games

I updated **Unity 5.3.4** to **5.4.1**. When I try to export project as APK for Android, I am getting following error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="D:/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlu;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlv;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlw;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlx;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzly;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlz;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzma;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmb;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmc;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:613)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:605)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive D:\Applications\Darbe\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs\.\unity-plugin-library.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/unity/
processing com/google/unity/BuildConfig.class...
ignored resource com/google/unity/ads/
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/CustomNativeAd.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/CustomNativeAd$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/CustomNativeAd$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$3$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$3$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$3$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeAdLoader$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/NativeExpressAd$6.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/PluginUtils.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityAdListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityCustomNativeAdListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityRewardBasedVideoAdListener.class...
processing archive D:\Applications\Darbe\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\MainLibProj\libs\.\play-games-plugin-support.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/games/
ignored resource com/google/games/bridge/
processing com/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/NativeBridgeActivity.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$1.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$TokenRequest.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenPendingResult.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenResult.class...
processing archive D:\Applications\Darbe\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource .readme
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource android/
ignored resource android/support/
ignored resource android/support/v7/
ignored resource android/support/v7/app/
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$LayoutParams.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$NavigationMode.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$OnMenuVisibilityListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$OnNavigationListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Tab.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$TabListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerArrowDrawableToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerToggle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$DummyDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$HoneycombDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$JellybeanMr2Delegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$ToolbarCompatDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb$SetIndicatorInfo.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$5.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$AlertParams$OnPrepareListViewListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$ButtonHandler.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertController$CheckedItemAdapter.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog$Builder.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase$ActionBarDrawableToggleImpl.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV23.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV23$AppCompatWindowCallbackV23.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$4.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$5.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$5$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$6.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ListMenuDecorView.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState$SavedState.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState$SavedState$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialogFragment.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatViewInflater.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NavItemSelectedListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$Builder.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$IceCreamSandwichExtender.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$JellybeanExtender.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$LollipopExtender.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat$MediaStyle.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompatImpl21.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompatImplBase.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$ActionMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$MenuBuilderCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$PanelMenuPresenterCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/TwilightCalculator.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/TwilightManager.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/TwilightManager$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/TwilightManager$TwilightState.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$2.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$3.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/WindowDecorActionBar$TabImpl.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/appcompat/
processing android/support/v7/appcompat/BuildConfig.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/graphics/
ignored resource android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/
processing android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawableUtils.class...
processing android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawableWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable.class...
processing android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable$ArrowDirection.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/text/
processing android/support/v7/text/AllCapsTransformationMethod.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/transition/
processing android/support/v7/transition/ActionBarTransition.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/view/
processing android/support/v7/view/ActionBarPolicy.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ActionMode.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ActionMode$Callback.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/CollapsibleActionView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ContextThemeWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/StandaloneActionMode.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportActionModeWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportMenuInflater.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatSet.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatSet$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/WindowCallbackWrapper.class...
ignored resource android/support/v7/view/menu/
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItem.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView$ActionMenuItemForwardingListener.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView$PopupCallback.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/BaseMenuPresenter.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/BaseMenuWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/BaseWrapper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ExpandedMenuView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ListMenuItemView.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ListMenuPresenter.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/ListMenuPresenter$MenuAdapter.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuBuilder.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuBuilder$Callback.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuBuilder$ItemInvoker.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuDialogHelper.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemImpl.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemImpl$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS.class...
processing android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$ActionProviderWrapper.<message truncated>
```

I updated **all plugins, Android SDKs and JDK**. My project's **min sdk is 9** (Android 2.3.1). I am using only [Google Analytics](https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-plugin-for-unity), [Google Play Games](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) and [Google Admob](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity) plugins. However I am still getting these error and I couldn't figure out how to fix this. Thanks.

**Note:** I deleted Unity completely install again as latest version. I clean projects and import then I import GooglePlayGames,GoogleAdMob,GoogleAnalytics in the given order and I am getting still same error. I applied all solutions to [given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980377/4606368) however didn't work so I don't think that question and this are not same.

**Note2:** **Google Play Services** seems to be up-to-date however I couldn't find the folder *google-play-services_lib/res* which referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018661/4606368).

[image: There is no folder which name is res]

**Note3:** I delete sdk, Android, Studio and Unity then clean install. I only import Google Play Games plugin and GoogleMobileAds plugin. Now it give the following error:

```
Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/GPGSAndroidSetupUI.cs(113,47): error CS1501: No overload for method `DoResolution' takes `3' arguments
```

I found that this is a [bug](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/272) of googlemobileads. After I re-imported these 2 plugins; *No overload for method DoResolution takes 3 arguments* gone and I am still getting same error *CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.* when I export apk.

Comment: I don't think so. Please read my note section. I try everything what described in the given answer.

Comment: Hi @UmairM this is not a duplication of that question. This is a bug on Google Play Games for Unity plugin.

Comment: I explained the general solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260722/error-building-player-commandinvokationfailure-unable-to-convert-classes-into/40644109#40644109

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a problem. Problem is unfortunately [Google Play Games for Unity Plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) After I deleted plugin, I can able to export APK.

**Update:** Using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpjX--0t6T8) and its source code I can able to export as APK. Apperantly, latest version of Google Play Games is broken and not working on Unity 5.4.1. Just use source code which given in the tutorial.

**Update 2:** As I understand; GoogleAnalytics V4, GooglePlayGames, GoogleAdMob plugins are not compatible with latest Android SDK and/or latest Unity

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check for duplicate classes in your project jars.
I had similar issue, in my case the problem was: Unity/Framework/Assets/Plugins/Android/android-support-v4.jar
Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe it is not related to duplicate classes. It is related following problems:

Google Analytics v4 plugin is not compatible with latest Android SDK & latest Unity. v3 is compatible.

Google Play Games plugin is not compatible with latest Android SDK & latest Unity.

AdMob plugin is not compatible with latest Android SDK & latest Unity.